# Clear memory saved previously with Ctrl + C

Tags: memory, copy-paste

Is there any keyboard shortcut to clear the memory of a copied text? For example: I copied a text and then I want to delete the text stored on Ctrl+C memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no shortcut for that..
There are programs(clipboardmanagers) for that or you can simply copy something else to "delete" the clipboard.